# Flutter app crashing with error 'Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest''

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter App crashing due to Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

I am trying to run a Flutter App. I get an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @62d72c82
```

This is the output of Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code
        that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Can anyone please explain the issue to me and
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.